# Basic PHP Security Issue

Tags: php, sql, security

So Im not really a backend developer, but I need to develop a basic password login. The (totally unreasonable) client has specifically said that he only wants a password input. No username or any other information can be passed.Since there aren't any users, there is only one password which I have coded directly into the script. Looks something like:

```
$password = $_POST['password']

if ($password == 'mypass') {

do something....

}
```

Is this vulnerable to some sort of injection hack? Are there any other huge security holes I should be worried about?

Comment: You could compare hashed pass against precomputed hash instead of plaintext, but if someone could read your source to find the pass, you've already got bigger problems. :-)

Comment: I hope that if you're sending the password over the wire, that you are at least using SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this vulnerable to some sort of injection hack?

No, because you're not injecting anything into anything else.

> Are there any other huge security holes I should be worried about?

- It has extremely low entropy, an attacker just automatically trying random passwords should not have too much trouble getting in. You're probably aware of that.
- If your server was ever breached and/or the source code revealed, the hardcoded password would be revealed and usable instantly. You could at least salt and hash it to prevent that much.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is not vulnerable or exploitable, however it can be improved.

I would suggest hashing your password and using srtcmp instead of the == operator.

Comment: And strcmp would improve things... how? passwords are either equal or not. Telling the user that their pw attemp is `<`,`=`,`>` would just lead to a 20-questions guessing game and make it far far easier to crack the pc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scenario where this is open to attack, which you may or may not suffer from.

Your example requires a user to post the password and, importantly, gives no indication that it is  maintaining a server-side session. If no session were to be in use, this would mean that only pages that contain this code, and to which the password is posted, would be  protected.

**If** you have developed a multi-page web application and have not put this password checking code into every single sensitive resource, you would be vulnerable to an authorisation-bypass attack.

e.g. If your site had pages at

1. http://example.com/  *public*
2. http://example.com/admin/  *private & protected*
3. http://example.com/admin/users.php *private & not protected*

A malicous user could access /admin/users.php directly, completely circumventing your authorisation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Always use one way hashing wherever possible, for storing in db table or hard coding. 
Instead of hard coding clear text password you can hardcode MD5 hash value of the password. Then calculate hash of the input from a user and then compare both. That way you do have fear of anyone stealing your code and leaking passwords with it.